# Filter related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Please refer to my models (3 models: Variant, Deal and Campaign) below.

I want to get a list of Variants and their related deals whose campaigns start date is today.

I have been able to filter the campaigns start date but, the list of deals being returned are not being filtered.

```
    def get_queryset(self):

    """

        Override get_queryset to cater for dynamic filtering

    """

    date_filters = []

    from_date = self.request.GET.get('from', None)

    if from_date is not None and len(from_date) > 0:
        date_filters.extend([Q(deal_set__campaign_start_date__gte=parse_date(from_date)),])
    else:
        date_filters.extend([Q(deal_set__campaign_start_date__gte=now()),])

    to_date = self.request.GET.get('to', None)

    if to_date is not None and len(to_date) > 0:
        date_filters.extend([Q(deal_set__campaign_end_date__lte=parse_date(to_date)),])

    return Variant.objects.filter(*date_filters).distinct()

class Variant(BaseModel):

    """

    Product model

    """

    variant_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.0'))
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Deal(BaseModel):

    """

    Deal model

    """

    deal_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Campaign(BaseModel):

    """

    Campaign model

    """

    campaign_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=now())
    end_date = models.DateField(default=now())
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You should probably post the code, where you show what you have already tried.

Comment: How about this: `today = date.today()` and `Variant.objects.filter(deal__campaign__start_date=today)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have all variants or only variants that have deals where the campaign start date is today?

For the latter it should be like this:

```
from datetime import date

Variant.objects.filter(deal_set__campaign__start_date=date.today())
```

Combine it with a `select_related` if needed.

Comment: It should be `filter(deal__...`, not `filter(deals__...`). Best regards!

Comment: Thanks. All deals are being returned (Not only the ones being filtered by campaign start date)

Comment: @Neelesh yes, the filter is for the Variant class only. You would need to use `myvariant.deal_set.filter(campaign__start_date=date.today())` to get the right deals then. I don't think you can do that in a single query.